# Call to undefined method DateTime :: getTimezone () error laravel Carbon

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

I am trying to show the date in laravel with a specific format using `$casts` in my model, but when I show in the view I get an error

> Call to undefined method DateTime :: getTimezone ()

and I do not know why this error is due.

Model

```
class Category extends Model
{
    use  SoftDeletes;

   protected $dates = ['created_at','updated_at','deleted_at'];

   protected $casts = [
        'created_at' => 'datetime:d-M-Y H:i:s',
        'updated_at' => 'datetime:d-M-Y H:i:s',
        'deleted_at' => 'datetime:d-M-Y H:i:s'
    ];
```

In my view

```
     <td>{{ $model->created_at }}</td>
     <td>{{ $model->updated_at }}</td>
     <td>{{ $model->deleted_at }}</td>
```

**Laravel 5.6**

Comment: [This](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/16983a689d15333e7101457c3e0c0d0b7da01d69/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php#L726) is the only instance of `getTimeZone` I could find in the Laravel code. However this function was [removed in PHP 5.5.0](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimezone.php). Looks like a bug to me. I have reported it to Laravel (https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/24886).

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace and the view code?

Comment: The strange thing is that I executed the comand composer dump-autoload twice and the error disappeared